# Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed - broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

My application have an implicit broadcast receiver to listen broadcast for incoming and outgoing calls even when the application is killed.

But when the application is killed i'm receiving the following error.

> E/InputDispatcher: channel 'd9c0aaa com.aswin.bt/com.aswin.bt.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

After that the broadcast receiver is not triggered.

The broadcast receiver works fine in all the android versions except Pie.

The application still receives broadcast when it is running in background.

**FYI : The MainActivity.java just have a textview in it**

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aswin.bt"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**CallReceiver.java**

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("aswin", "onReceive: " );
}
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.aswin.bt">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <receiver
                android:name=".CallReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: There's nothing else in the logcat? Are you even getting an `"onReceive: "`?

Comment: @greeble31 yes, onReceived is called only when the app is running. Once it is killed the broadcast receiver is not working.